# Slash into input text and class.upload.php doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a simple form to upload products in a database:
Name and image.
For the name, i use the standard input text field and for the image i'm using the class class.upload.php to resize and rename it.

It would work fine, but if i use a product name with the slash inside, something like: **article 6/10 - 10/10 - 20/10** sends me to crash the class for resizing image. Does not meet the dimensions given and I have always renamed it to **10.jpg** instead as something like: 03110e1afaf5c168e83a0cf18eed368e.jpg

So, article: 610 - 1010 - 2010 works

article: 6/10 - 10/10 - 20/10 doesn't work

This is the script i use:

```
  function addProduct()

   {
     include('class.upload.php'); 

$catId       = $_POST['cboCategory'];
$name        = $_POST["txtName"];

$width = 800;

$immagine = $_FILES['fleImage']['tmp_name'];
$dimensioni = getimagesize($immagine);
$larghezza = $dimensioni[0];
$altezza = $dimensioni[1];


if ($larghezza>$width)
 {         


   $db_name = str_replace(" ","_",$name);
   $image1 = md5(rand() * time()) . ".$db_name";  
   $fileName = pathinfo($image1, PATHINFO_FILENAME );


  $handle = new upload($_FILES['fleImage']);
    if ($handle->uploaded) {
     $handle->file_new_name_body   =    $fileName;
     $handle->image_resize     = true;
     $handle->image_x          = 800;
     $handle->image_ratio_y    = true;

  $handle->process('../../images/product/');


  // thumbnail

   $db_name = str_replace(" ","_",$name);
   $image2 = md5(rand() * time()) . ".$db_name";  
   $thumb = pathinfo($image2, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

  $handle->file_new_name_body   =   $thumb;
  $handle->image_resize     = true;
  $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
  $handle->image_x          = 360;
  $handle->image_y          = 270;

  $handle->process('../../images/product/');   

  if ($handle->processed) {
      // header("Location: index.php"); 
      $handle->clean();
  } else {
      echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
  }
}


$thumbnail = $thumb.'.jpg';
$main_image = $fileName.'.jpg';

$sql   = "INSERT INTO tbl_product (cat_id, pd_name, pd_image, pd_thumbnail, pd_date)
        VALUES ('$catId', '$name', '$main_image', '$thumbnail', NOW())";

 $result = dbQuery($sql);

 header("Location: index.php?catId=$catId");    

 }
  }
```

Comment: So, why not just do the same for what you're using to replace spaces with underscores? Replace the slashes with something else.

Comment: Why replace the slashes? it'a part of the article name. i can't replace it
Anyway what has to do the input text name with the class?

Comment: What about one function to handle the article's  filename and another of the uploading?

Comment: I don't understand, what has to do the input text name with the class.upload.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image1 = md5(rand() * time()) . ".$db_name";
```

At this point $image1 contains something like "03110e1afaf5c168e83a0cf18eed368earticle6/10_-*10/10*-_20/10"

```
$fileName = pathinfo($image1, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
```

pathinfo cuts everything but the file name, in this case $filename == "10"
Later you concatenate the ending ".jpg"